# Redirect class exit()

Tags: php, oop

I have a question about OOP:

I'm just starting with OOP in PHP. Now I've been following a tutorial and in that tutorial they made a class for redirecting.

```
class Redirect {

     public function to($target) {

          header('location '. $target);

     }

}
```

Now I'm wondering if it is required to `exit;` after the `header();`

Comment: It depends on whether or not you have anything else to do.

Comment: It's just ment for redirecting. `Redirect::to('index.php);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's generally a good practice to use `exit;` after sending a `Location: header`.  Otherwise the script execution is not terminated. The rest of the code will get executed which is not at all needed after a redirect.